# Unable to get DateTimepicker in HTML5

Tags: php, html

I have an issue with date-time picker in html 5, every time i get only text view rather then drop-down picker. I am doing like

```
<input type="datetime" id="datetimepic" name="datetimepic">
```

I am follow below link but cant get solution. please help me. thanks in advance.

http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-form-input-type/

Comment: `inpit` should be `input`??? or typo?

Comment: are you using bootstap? if yes then I can show you the way to display it.

Comment: type date time is browser dependent why not use jquery datetime plugin instead.

Comment: @mujahed: I wouldnt use the old bootstraps datepicker. when u give 111111111111 as year for example, it will crash the browser

Comment: then what was your solution :)

Comment: see the answer, set `type="datetime-local"` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime-local` as your field type.

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetimepic" name="datetimepic"/>
```

Comment: yes its work fine but i have to add time manually. i dont want this. thanks for your reply @gre_gor

Comment: what DO you want then, for me, typ in 4 number is sure much faster then choose from a number from 0 to 23 and then another one from 0 to 59...